# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in php while inputing String from Android app

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
 public function StoreUserInfo($sid, $name, $email, $password, $ktp, $gender) {
    $hash = $this->hashFunction($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"];
    $salt = $hash["salt"];

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET name = $name , email = $email , encrypted_password = $encrypted_password , salt = $salt, ktp = $ktp , gender = $gender WHERE sid = '$sid'");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $sid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt, $ktp, $gender);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name, email, encrypted_password, salt, ktp, gender FROM user WHERE sid = $sid");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $sid);
        if ($stmt === FALSE) {
        die($mysqli->error);}
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt-> bind_result($token1,$token2,$token3,$token4,$token5,$token6,$token7);
        while ( $stmt-> fetch() ) {
           $user["sid"] = $token1;
           $user["name"] = $token2;
           $user["email"] = $token3;
           $user["ktp"] = $token6;
           $user["gender"] = $token7;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in input!";
        echo json_encode($response);
      return false;
    }
}
```

I have this code and error shows

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `bind_param()` on boolean in line 7

do I should not use `prepare()` on UPDATE ?

but when I remove it, it shows same error in line 13

then I need `bind_param()` right ?

what should I do ?

by the way my input updated in table, but i want to check it and return it true.

Comment: You are not using prepared query properly `name = $name ` ?? In query you should place placeholders not directly variables

Comment: You need to bind the variables, not inject them right into the querystring.

Comment: you can do some search here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid actually the input updated in the table , i just want to make sure is it true or not. place holder is like a = $name ??

Comment: I'm really curious what the hashFunction method does. It's generally considered a terrible idea to roll your own crypto - you should be using the built in password lib in PHP

Comment: Question are you using `mysqli_` or `PDO` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using prepare / bind the wrong way...

## The `mysqli_` nameless version :

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE user 
    SET name = ?, 
        email = ? , 
        encrypted_password = ? , 
        salt = ?, 
        ktp = ?, 
        gender = ? 
    WHERE sid =?');

  $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", 
        $name, 
        $email, 
        $encrypted_password, 
        $salt, 
        $ktp, 
        $gender,
        $sid
        );

  $result = $stmt->execute();
```

## The PDO one :

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE user 
    SET name = :name, 
        email = :email , 
        encrypted_password = :encrypted_password , 
        salt = :salt, 
        ktp = :ktp, 
        gender = :gender 
    WHERE sid =:sid');
// $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $sid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt, $ktp, $gender);
$result = $stmt->execute(array(
        ':name'=>$name, 
        ':email'=>$email, 
        ':encrypted_password'=>$encrypted_password, 
        ':salt'=>$salt, 
        ':ktp'=>$ktp, 
        ':gender'=>$gender,
        ':sid'=>$sid,
        )
    );
```

Comment: `$stmt->execute(` , shouldn't that be `$stmt->execute(array (` instead ? :)  ( I'm not sure, I didn't try it )

Comment: @gregn3 you're dam' right, I should proof read before posting... u_u

Comment: Please don't do `var_dump($this->conn->error);` JFYI: [PHP error reportig](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)

Comment: the errors is disappear but the all the input was " " , why was that ?

Comment: @RavenNyo you mean all your data in the table is set to `''` or just the line with the goo sid ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I can't put a proper error handling without loosing the readability of the answer, but yes, var_dump is for development purpose only.

Comment: 1. you can. 2. "development mode" makes no sense whatsoever. Keeping two versions of code, one for production and one for debugging is just insane

Comment: @Blag yes only sid have input, the rest is " ", then i want to update string into the " "

Comment: @RavenNyo is the update working ? like does it change data (even if it's just change to "") ? check on phpmyadmin side.

Comment: @Blag i think its working since its success on android app,  but i think '?' didn't get the String input, because when i use $name instead '?' the update work fine.

Comment: @Blag can i use something instead of SET ? like INTO or something ?

Comment: @RavenNyo what is your table user definition ? everything is string ? I'm thinking about your `"sssssss"`

Comment: @Blag yes everything is String